# How to set an Environment Object in preview

Tags: swift, swiftui

My view needs an environment object which is set in the SceneDelegate by adding it to the window.rootViewController. How can I set an environment object to be used for the preview?

Comment: Have you tried adding a .environmentObject() to the view in the preview?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You add it using .environmentObject(_:) modifier:

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(YourObject())
    }
}
```

Comment: Doh! Thanks for the help!

Comment: What if you want some data sortof predefined in the model? Like YourObject.theArrayInside = [1, 2, 3]

Comment: @GinTonyx If you want to set your object's property, you can do it like this:
```objc

static var previews: some View {

        let state = SearchViewState()

        state.wubis = [previewWord]

        return SearchListView()

            .environmentObject(state)

    }

```

Answer (score 10):

This userData property gets its value automatically, as long as the **`environmentObject(_:)`** modifier has been applied to a parent.

```swift
struct UserList: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Toggle(isOn: $userData.showFavoritesOnly) {
                    Text("Users Fav only")
                }
                
                ForEach(landmarkData) { landmark in
                    if !self.userData.showFavoritesOnly || landmark.isFavorite {
                        NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)) {
                            UserRow(landmark: landmark)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Users"))
        }
    }
}

struct UserList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        UserList()
            .environmentObject(UserData())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the new [@Observable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro) macro, your model might not conform to ObservableObject. In that case, you'll need to use `.environment()` to add your environment

```
#Preview {
     
     var model = YourObject()
     
     return VStack{
          TransformationTile()
     }.environment(model)
}
```

This [section](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro#Migrate-other-source-code) specifically talks about the new way to pass around your `@Observable` models.