# Initialize object in SwiftUI preview

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

**Edit**: I've deleted the preview entirely and am just passing the object as an argument in the view, from the master view. I'm getting this:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'GoOsc.GpInstanceModel.Type' to expected argument type 'GoOsc.GpInstanceModel'
```

My understanding is that a preview needs default values for any `@EnvironmentObject` parameters that it uses...

```
struct GigView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    GigView().environmentObject(GoOsc())
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

This code throws up...

```
// Missing arguments for parameters 'gpInstanceMain', 'gpInstanceBackup' in call
```

It's asking for two variables of my custom object type, set like this in the main body...

```
var gpInstanceMain: GoOsc.GpInstanceModel
var gpInstanceBackup: GoOsc.GpInstanceModel
```

It's easy enough to set defaults for some strings, but I don't know what to do in this case. It's out of scope, since its the preview, so I can't access the populated objects to use as a preview.

So my question is how do I initialize my object "by hand"?

This is the struct it is derived from...

```
struct GpInstanceModel {
var gpSongName: String
var gpSongNumber: String
var gpSongPartName: Array<String>
var gpSongPartNumber: Array<String>
var gpCurrentSongPartName: String
var gpCurrentSongPartNumber: String
init() {
    gpSongName = ""
    gpSongNumber = ""
    gpSongPartName = Array(repeating: "", count: 8)
    gpSongPartNumber = Array(repeating: "", count: 8)
    gpCurrentSongPartName = ""
    gpCurrentSongPartNumber = ""
}
}
```

Xcode suggests this (in <>)

```
struct GigView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    GigView(gpInstanceMain: <#GoOsc.GpInstanceModel#>, gpInstanceBackup: <#GoOsc.GpInstanceModel#>).environmentObject(GoOsc())
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
}
}
```

Comment: this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57781982/how-to-set-an-environment-object-in-preview may answer you question

Comment: Thanks @workingdog ... tried that too and it doesn't seem to make a difference. I've added it to my post to avoid confusion, though.

Answer (score 0):

how about just this:

```
struct GigView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    GigView(gpInstanceMain: GpInstanceModel(), gpInstanceBackup: GpInstanceModel())
        .environmentObject(GoOsc())
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
   }
}
```

Comment: Hm, XCode says its not in scope.

Comment: if it's not in scope, maybe you need to "import GoOsc" in your file.

Comment: could you show how you initialize "GigView", including the init(...) if any?
Is "GigView_Previews" in the same file as "GigView"?